# Form show select box after choice option on select

Tags: php, html

I intend that after selecting an option from a list, a new list appears according to the option selected.

But the second select list, sends a query to the database, depending on the choice list in the first select!

example:

- table bd

| A | 1 |

| A | 2 |

| B | 3 |

| B | 4 |

- first select

A or B

- second select

if select A

1

2

if select B

3

4

Comment: Where's your code? What have you tried? No one is going to write this code for you from scratch. You need to, at least, make an attempt.

Comment: You're going to need some client-side script for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple search for a filtered dropdown list brought me to the following code on GitHub which does a decent job explaining how to program one of these lists on your own. You can find it [here.](https://github.com/dnasir/jquery-cascading-dropdown)

Hope this helps.